# Problem with shortcode inside a shortcode

Tags: functions, shortcode

I use this in my Functions.php file to format short codes for some jQuery UI tabs, however I also use a short tag to reference my video embeds, which breaks when they're inside the UI tabs.

My question is, how would I just pass my video short code through this function unaltered:

```
// jQuery UI Tabs
add_shortcode( 'tabgroup', 'etdc_tab_group' );
function etdc_tab_group( $atts, $content ){
$GLOBALS['tab_count'] = 0;

do_shortcode( $content );

if( is_array( $GLOBALS['tabs'] ) ){
foreach( $GLOBALS['tabs'] as $tab ){
$tabs[] = '<li><a class="" href="#'.$tab['title'].'">'.$tab['title'].'</a></li>';
$panes[] = '<div id="'.$tab['title'].'"><h3>'.$tab['title'].'</h3>'.$tab['content'].'</div>';
}
$return = "\n".'<!-- the tabs --><div id="tabs"><ul>'.implode( "\n", $tabs ).'</ul>'."\n".'<!-- tab "panes" -->'.implode( "\n", $panes ).'</div>'."\n";
}
return $return;
}

add_shortcode( 'tab', 'etdc_tab' );
function etdc_tab( $atts, $content ){
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
'title' => 'Tab %d'
), $atts));

$x = $GLOBALS['tab_count'];
$GLOBALS['tabs'][$x] = array( 'title' => sprintf( $title,   $GLOBALS['tab_count'] ), 'content' =>  $content );
$GLOBALS['tab_count']++;
}
```

My video short code looks like this [video src="http://site.com/uploads/example.mp4"]. I imagine I just have to set something in $GLOBALS, but I don't know how I would just pass it through unaltered.

(My 'video' short code is being translated by another plugin)

Update: This was the solution to my problem. Adding `do_shortcode` to $panes:

```
$panes[] = '<div id="'.$tab['title'].'"><h3>'.$tab['title'].'</h3>'.do_shortcode($tab['content']).'</div>';
```

Comment: try adding do_shortcode( $content );
 to etdc_tab function

Comment: @Bainternet Moving the do_shortcode($content); to the etdc_tab function, doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick that `wp-includes/media.php` uses for the `embed` shortcode: first remove all shortcodes, then add a specific shortcode back to the system, filter your content for it, then re-register the original shortcodes.

Try this:

```
function etdc_tab_group( $atts, $content ){
  global $shortcode_tags;
  $GLOBALS['tab_count'] = 0;

  // save the shortcode registrations
  $orig_shortcode_tags = $shortcode_tags;
  // remove them all
  remove_all_shortcodes();
  // add ours back in
  add_shortcode( 'tab', 'etdc_tab' );
  $content = do_shortcode( $content );
  // restore original shortcodes
  $shortcode_tags = $orig_shortcode_tags;

  //...rest of the function...
}
```

Actually, now that I'm looking at that `etdc_tab_group()` function more closely, I'm suprised it's not breaking something... Did you copy and paste it directly, or did you edit anything out? Because it's never passing `$content` back out again.

So first thing I'd try is just commenting out the `do_shortcode()` call and see how that works. If that breaks something else, then try the method above?